# Using PLSQL, how can I access a column in a select loop using a variable for the column name?

Tags: for-loop, plsql

I need to be able to access a loop column by using a variable of the column name.
How can I resolve the error below?  I will need to access multiple columns whose names are defined elsewhere.

```
declare
column_name_var varchar2(255) := 'address';
begin
for row in (select '5' as id, '123 x' as address from dual) LOOP
    --  access the column directly with name ID - no problem
    dbms_output.put_line(row.id);   
    --  how can I use the variable to access the column with the name of 'address'?
    dbms_output.put_line(row.column_name_var);    -- ERROR
end loop;
end;
```

The way I loop through the data is not in question unless it affects the answer and syntax I can use.

I need to loop through data and once I get the row, I need to be able to access a column.  But this column may change depending on the user.  I can get the column name for the specific user into a variable.  I then need to be able to access that column using the column name from the variable.  This is the syntax that I need.   Something similar to the following but these do not work:

row.column_name_var,
row[column_name_var]

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a cursor instead of your current loop?

Declare this:

```
CURSOR c
IS
  SELECT clause;
v_c c%ROWTYPE;
```

Use the code below to get your results

```
OPEN c
FETCH c INTO v_c
WHILE c%FOUND LOOP
  -- Your code here. To get a result, use v_c.rowname
END LOOP;
```

I do not understand and also would highly disadvise you to attempt to use a variable to read your current row. What you can though do is create an if statement to only retrieve the rows you need depending on the input parameters. Simply always retrieve all of them, which you may need.

Comment: I'm not sure if using a defined cursor instead of an inline one would help solve the issue asked in the question.  I'm not putting the row into a variable, I need to access a column from the row where the column name is defined by a variable.

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011) is probably what you were looking for. The only way to get the value from a certain column is to use dynamic sql.